# Oracle query results don't match Enterprise Manager values

Tags: sql, database, oracle, tablespace, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am trying to get the size of all tablespaces on an Oracle database.
I have tried 2 ways of getting the info.

Option 1 gives me good values, but it doesn't give return any values when the tablespace doesn't have a database file. Specifically, it isn't returning any values for the "TEMP" and "TESTTODELETE" tablespaces.

[image]

The only differences I've noticed between these 2 tablespaces and the others are that these 2 don't have .dbf files.

[image]

Option 2 gives me the correct values for some tablespaces, but is totally off other times. Option 2 does return something for the "TEMP" tablespace, but it doesn't return anything for the "TESTTODELETE" tablespace.

[image]

Both options don't return any information for the tablespace "TESTTODELETE".

**What is the best way to get the tablespace total size in MB for all tablespaces so that it reflects what is displayed in the Enterprise Manager?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dba_data_files` contains just that, tablespaces that have data files.  If you need to include tablespaces that aren't backed by data files (e.g. temp tablespaces), you'll need to include [`dba_temp_files`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4158.htm#REFRN23288) in your query.  They have almost exactly the same column layout so it should be easy to `UNION` them together.

As for `dba_tablespace_usage_metrics`, the capacity it reports is the *maximum* size for a tablespace.  If a tablespace has autoextend enabled it will include that in the calculation.  Furthermore, I don't recommend relying on the `v$parameters` to determine block size.  Instead, join to `dba_tablespaces` because each tablespace can have its own block size.